# Can't get appropriate value in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a little problem with the following piece of code where I query a database and use the results to populate a dynamic table. There seems to be no problem with the query, but the for loop does not pick up the appropriate values from above. How could I fix that

```
//grab result from doneon table and show on report
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM doneon WHERE SampID LIKE ?', id, (err, rows, fields) => {
    if(err){
      return console.log('An error ocurred with the query', err)
    }
    var tabldiv = document.getElementById('tabldivid')
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

    // table.style.border = '3px solid black'
    table.style.width = '100%'
    table.id = 'tablid'
    table.appendChild(tableBody);

    var heading = new Array();
    heading[0] = "Test"
    heading[1] = "Result"
    heading[2] = "Normal values"

    for(i=0; i <rows.length; i += 1) {
      var resu = new Array()
      resu[i] = rows[i]
      console.log(rows[i]);
    }

    //TABLE COLUMNS
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    for (i = 0; i < heading.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement('TH')
        th.width = '75';
        th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(heading[i]));
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    //TABLE ROWS
    for (i = 0; i < resu.length; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        for (j = 0; j < resu[i].length; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resu[i][j]));
            tr.appendChild(td)
        }
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    }
    tabldiv.appendChild(table)
  })
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(rows[i]);`?

Comment: You are defining the variable `resu` as a `new Array` at each iteration of your first for loop; The i-th element of this new array is then assigned some value from the row array which produces an array containing mostly undefined values. https://javascript.info/array should help you get to a point where you can provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello Ben, console.log(rows[i]) gives me rowdatapacket that's why I don't understand when it then says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. When I do console.log(rows.length), it does give me a value

Comment: Hello John, alright I will check out the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John is correct that you are initializing a new `resu` array every iteration of the for loop. By initializing a new `resu` array every iteration, you are only populating the i-th index of `resu`, then on the next iteration, the `resu` variable gets reinitialized again, and the old data that *was* populating `resu` gets overwritten. This will leave *all* indexes in `resu` as undefined *except* the current i-th index.

For example, let's say the result of your SQL query gives us the following `rows` array:

```
rows = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
```

This is what is happening to the data in `resu` on each loop (note the undefined indexes starting at iteration 2):

**Iteration 1:** `resu = ['a'];`

**Iteration 2:** `resu = [,'b'];`

**Iteration 3:** `resu = [,,'c'];`

**Iteration 4:** `resu = [,,,'d'];`

...and so on. Then when you run the for loop on the 0-th index on `resu`, the 0-th index is undefined. This is why you get an undefined error on the 3rd for loop, but you still get a result when console.logging `resu.length` and `rows.length`

But I'm actually wondering if you need a separate `resu` array at all. I believe you would get the same result from simply iterating over the `rows` array to create the table rows:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    ......
    for (j = 0; j < rows[i].length; j++) {
        ......
    }
}
```

This way you can totally omit your first for loop. If you do need a duplicate of the `rows` array for some reason you can still omit the for loop and instead you should initialize it this way:

```
var resu = rows;
```

This will still make a duplicate array, but it will reduce your runtime since you're not iterating over an array needlessly.

Comment: Hey Robert, Thanks a lot. I ended up taking the simple route and wrote values directly to HTML through javascript to create my table. It's simple and will do for now.